# Constructing all Semidirect Products $C_p \rtimes C_p$ for $p$ Prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, semidirect-product

I'd just like to check my understanding and to see if my thinking is right.

I'm tasked with constructing all semidirect products of $C_p$ by $C_p$ where $C_p$ is the cyclic group of prime order $p$.

Firstly, $C_p \cong \mathbb{Z} /p\mathbb{Z}$, and $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_p) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$. To construct all semidirect products, I then simply need to consider all homomorphisms $\tau: \mathbb{Z}_p \to Aut(\mathbb{Z}_p)$. However, these are cyclic groups of coprime order, and so the only homomorphism is the trivial one, $x \mapsto 0$, and so $\mathbb{Z} /p\mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z} /p\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z} /p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} /p\mathbb{Z}$, where the latter is the direct product.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. ${}{}{}$

Comment: That's correct. A different route to the same destination goes via the oft seen exercise that all groups of order $p^2$ are abelian.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is correct. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

To fill in on Jyrki's comment, let $A$ be a group of order $p^2$, and let us show it is abelian. To this end, recall that any $p$-group has nontrivial center, and also recall that the center-quotient $G/Z$ of any non-abelian group cannot be cyclic. Since any group of order $p$ is cyclic, any group of order $p^2$ is thus abelian. Remark that every group of order $p$ is abelian, but the Heisenberg group (of parameter $p$) is an example of a non-abelian group of order $p^3$.

Comment: Right - to wit, all subgroups of an Abelian group are normal, and so we have a semidirect product of two normal subgroups, which is just the direct product, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Since the kernel is trivial or the whole group, a nontrivial homomorphism would be an embedding. But $p\nmid p-1$, and hence this is impossible. Just to say that the cyclicity of $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_p)$ is not essential here, and the weaker $\left|\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_p)\right|=p-1$ suffices.